# async function does not update after successful deletion of an item from an API with Vue3

Tags: django-rest-framework, fetch, vuejs3

After successfully deleting an item from an api, the list of items updates only after the second click on the same item.
Using fetch, vue 3 composition API and django rest api. Created an async function for both getting data from an api and deleting data from it. How can you update/ make a get request for the objects once one of the items in the list is deleted?

```
<template>
  <div id="restTodo">
    <div class="TodoContainer">
      <div v-for="todo in todos" v-bind:key="todo.id" class="TodoComponent">
        <div class="TodoValue">{{ todo.todo }}</div>
        <div class="TodoValue">{{ todo.completion }}</div>
        <button class="TodoValue" id="buttonComplete">+</button>
        <button
          class="TodoValue"
          id="buttonDelete"
          @click="removeTodo(todo.id)"
        >
          X
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const todos = ref([]);

    const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo-list/";

    const API_DELETE = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo-delete";

    async function getTodos() {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL);
      const json = await response.json();
      todos.value = json;
    }

    // // // // // // // // // // // //
    function getCookie(name) {
      let cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
          // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return cookieValue;
    }

    const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
    // // // // // // // // // // // //

    async function removeTodo(id) {
      var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
      fetch(`${API_DELETE}/${id}/`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
      })
      // .then(console.log(`deleted item ${id}`))
      .then(getTodos())
    }

    // // // // // // // // // // // //
    onMounted(() => {
      getTodos();
    });
    // // // // // // // // // // // //

    return {
      todos,
      removeTodo,
      csrftoken,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, changing the removeTodo function .then updates things.

```
async function removeTodo(id) {
  var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
  fetch(`${API_DELETE}/${id}/`, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    getTodos()
    return response
  })
}
```